# How to give message when Threadpool Executor is completed?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to give a pop up alert message when my ThreadpoolExecutor is finished executing. It is searching email addresses from websites, once it is done I want a alert message as "Completed". Here is my Thread :-

```
public class Constant
    {
      public  static final int NUM_OF_THREAD = 60;
      public  static final int TIME_OUT = 10000;
    }
    ThreadPoolExecutor poolMainExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool
            (Constant.NUM_OF_THREAD);
```

Here is my Searching Operation class :-

```
class SearchingOperation implements Runnable {

        URL urldata;
        int i;
        Set<String> emailAddresses;
        int level;

        SearchingOperation(URL urldata, int i, Set<String> emailAddresses, int level) {
            this.urldata = urldata;
            this.i = i;
            this.emailAddresses = emailAddresses;
            this.level = level;
            if (level != 1)
                model.setValueAt(urldata.getProtocol() + "://" + urldata.getHost() + "/contacts", i, 3);

        }

        public void run() {
            BufferedReader bufferreader1 = null;
            InputStreamReader emailReader = null;
            System.out.println(this.i + ":" + poolMainExecutor.getActiveCount() + ":" + level + ";" + urldata.toString());

            try {
                if (level < 1) {
                    String httpPatternString = "https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#=]{2,256}\\.[a-z]{2,6}\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\+.~#?&//=]*)";
                    String httpString = "";
                    BufferedReader bufferreaderHTTP = null;
                    InputStreamReader httpReader = null;
                    try {

                        httpReader = new InputStreamReader(urldata.openStream());
                        bufferreaderHTTP = new BufferedReader(httpReader
                        );
                        StringBuilder rawhttp = new StringBuilder();
                        while ((httpString = bufferreaderHTTP.readLine()) != null) {

                            rawhttp.append(httpString);

                        }
                        if (rawhttp.toString().isEmpty()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        List<String> urls = getURL(rawhttp.toString());
                        for (String url : urls) {
                            String fullUrl = getMatchRegex(url, httpPatternString);
                            if (fullUrl.isEmpty()) {
                                if (!url.startsWith("/")) {
                                    url = "/" + url;
                                }

                                String address = urldata.getProtocol() + "://" + urldata.getHost() + url;
                                fullUrl = getMatchRegex(address, httpPatternString);

                            }
                            if (!addressWorked.contains(fullUrl) && fullUrl.contains(urldata.getHost())) {
                                addressWorked.add(fullUrl);
                                sendToSearch(fullUrl);

                            }
                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //System.out.println("652" + e.getMessage());
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            if (httpReader != null)
                                bufferreaderHTTP.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            if (httpReader != null)
                                httpReader.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }
                }
                String someString = "";
                emailReader = new InputStreamReader(urldata.openStream());
                bufferreader1 = new BufferedReader(
                        emailReader);
                StringBuilder emailRaw = new StringBuilder();
                while ((someString = bufferreader1.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (someString.contains("@")) {
                        emailRaw.append(someString).append(";");
                    }
                }
                //Set<String> emailAddresses = new HashSet<String>();
                String emailAddress;
                //Pattern pattern = Pattern
                //.compile("\\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\b");
                Pattern
                        pattern = Pattern
                        .compile("\\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\b");

                Matcher matchs = pattern.matcher(emailRaw);
                while (matchs.find()) {
                    emailAddress = (emailRaw.substring(matchs.start(),
                            matchs.end()));
                    //  //System.out.println(emailAddress);
                    if (!emailAddresses.contains(emailAddress)) {
                        emailAddresses.add(emailAddress);
                        //  //System.out.println(emailAddress);
                        if (!foundItem.get(i)) {
                            table.setValueAt("Found", i, 4);
                            foundItem.set(i, true);
                        }

                        String emails = !emailAddresses.isEmpty() ? emailAddresses.toString() : "";
                        model.setValueAt(emails, i, 2);
                        model.setValueAt("", i, 3);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //System.out.println("687" + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bufferreader1 != null)
                        bufferreader1.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    if (emailReader != null)
                        emailReader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            }
        }
```

After this the final snippet :-

```
 private void sendToSearch(String address) throws Throwable {
            SearchingOperation operation = new SearchingOperation(new URL(address), i,
                    emailAddresses, level + 1);
            //operation.run();
            try {
                final Future handler = poolMainExecutor.submit(operation);

                try {
                    handler.get(Constant.TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    handler.cancel(false);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //System.out.println("Time out for:" + address);
            } catch (Error error) {
                //System.out.println("Time out for:" + address);

            } finally {
            }
        }
```

Comment: The Google Guava library has an implementation for that: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained

Comment: You should make it clearer wether you want to know when your executor is completed, or the task you submitted to it is. These are two different things. (Bonus point 1: the implementation of the task is irrelevant, wether you are downloading stuff or printing Hello World, your problem is the same, so no need to dump 100 lines :-). Please note : using non concurrent datastrcutures inside multiple threads is a recipe for bugs, case in point, your `Set<String> emailAdress`. Do NOT share non concurrent data structures between threads.

Comment: You have only one task ("poolMainExecutor.submit(operation);"). That means that calling operation.run(); would be at least as fast as using the ThreadPoolExecutor since it can only use one of the 60 Threads you assigned. Is this on purpose, an error or part of the question?

Comment: In Future Object you can check it by using isDone() method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()

Comment: @piegames Then how do I execute all the tasks and display a message as "Completed" when all emails are found?

Comment: @piegames Another thing, I want to start SearchingOperation on button click, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can be used., it will check whether the execution is completed in every 2.5 seconds.

```
do {
        System.out.println("In Progress");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (poolMainExecutor.getActiveCount() != 0);

    System.out.println("Completed");
```

Comment: Avoid polling in regular time intervals if there is the possibility to wait or to get notified (in fact that's both the same).

Comment: @Jobin Thanks! This while (poolMainExecutor.getActiveCount() != 0); helped me. But one concern, when I use this, my other processes are not displayed while the process is running. After "Completed" status comes, then I am able to see the output. I want to see all the processes running concurrently.

Comment: @Jobin  I got the solution. I put it in another thread and run it.

Comment: @Jobin Another thing, I want to start SearchingOperation on button click, how can I do it?

Comment: that is pretty straight forward rt? what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @Jobin The issue is when I am clicking on search for the first time, searching operation is working fine and all emails are extracted. But when I click the search button second time all emails are not extracted. This issue is occurring when I have duplicate domain names whose emails are already been extracted for the first time

Answer (score 2):

Implement `Callable<Void>` instead of `Runnable` and wait for all the task to terminate by calling `Future<Void>.get()`:

```
class SearchingOperation implements Callable<Void>
{
   public Void call() throws Exception
   {
      //same code as in run()
   }
}

//submit and wait until the task complete
Future<Void> future = poolMainExecutor.submit(new SearchingOperation()).get();
```

Comment: Where do I put this line?
Future<Void> future = poolMainExecutor.submit(new SearchingOperation()).get();

Comment: After creating `poolMainExecutor`

Comment: Which one? And when?

Comment: @piegames I am not able to add Future<Void> future = poolMainExecutor.submit(new SearchingOperation()).get();

it is showing error

Comment: I (think I) found the error: it has to be 
poolMainExecutor.submit(new SearchingOperation()).get(); or Future<Void> future = poolMainExecutor.submit(new SearchingOperation()); future.get();

Either way, this code will wait until the *current* task is finished. It won't help you if you need to wait for *all* the tasks to be done.

Comment: @piegames If you call `Future.get()` on *all* tasks' `Future`s, then it *does* wait until all are done.

Comment: @ortis Another thing, I want to start SearchingOperation on button click, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination()`:

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

As in your code, you create your `ThreadPoolExecutor` first

```
ThreadPoolExecutor poolMainExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Constant.NUM_OF_THREAD);
```

Then, you need to add Tasks to it:

```
poolMainExecutor.execute(myTask);
poolMainExecutor.submit(myTask);
```

`execute` will return nothing, while `submit` will return a `Future` object. Tasks must implement `Runnable` or `Callable`. An object of `SearchingOperation` is a task for example. The thread pool will execute the tasks in parallel, but each task will be executed by one thread. That means to effectively use `NUM_OF_THREAD` Threads you need to add at least `NUM_OF_THREAD` Tasks.

(Optional) Once you got all jobs to work, shutdown your pool. This will prevent new tasks from being submitted. It won't affect running tasks.

```
poolMainExecutor.shutdown();
```

At the end, you need to wait for all Tasks to complete. The easiest way is by calling

```
poolMainExecutor.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

You should adjust the amount of time you want to wait for the tasks to finish before throwing an exception.

Now that the work is done, notify the user. A simple way is to call one of the Dialog presets from JOptionPane, like:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "message", "title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

It will popup a little window with title "title", the message "message", an "information" icon and a button to close it.

Comment: Too complicated..cannot understand it bro!

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is when all emails are extracted from the website, I should get a pop up as completed. Please help me with an exact solution or make changes in the above code that I have provided.